# Column that is the SUM of another column if a cell is equivelant

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on building a relativly complex query:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY TSK.[Status] DESC
        ) AS 'RowNumber'
    ,PDT.[Name] AS Project
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN (
                    STY.KanBanProductId IS NOT NULL
                    AND STY.SprintId IS NULL
                    )
                THEN 'KanBan'
            WHEN (
                    STY.KanBanProductId IS NULL
                    AND STY.SprintId IS NOT NULL
                    )
                THEN 'Sprint'
            END
        ) AS ProjectType
    ,STY.[Number] StoryNumber
    ,STY.Title AS StoryTitle
    ,TSK.[Name] AS Task
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), STY.Effort) AS StoryPoints

    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), TSK.OriginalEstimateHours) AS TaskHoursEstimate
    ,ISNULL(SUM(DTH.[Hours]), 0) AS WorkHours
    ,MAX(CASE 
            WHEN DTH.Hours != 0
                THEN DTH.ActivityDate
            END) AS LatestActivityDate
    ,TSK.[Status] AS [Status]
FROM Task TSK
LEFT JOIN DailyTaskHours DTH ON TSK.PK_Task = DTH.TaskId
LEFT JOIN Story STY ON TSK.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
LEFT JOIN Sprint SPT ON STY.SprintId = SPT.PK_Sprint
LEFT JOIN Product PDT ON STY.ProductId = PDT.PK_Product
WHERE TSK.PointPerson LIKE @userParam
    AND TSK.[Status] LIKE @statusParam
    AND PDT.[Name] != 'Overhead Codes'
GROUP BY LEN(STY.[Number])
    ,STY.[Number]
    ,TSK.[Status]
    ,STY.Title
    ,PDT.[Name]
    ,TSK.CreateDate
    ,TSK.[Name]
    ,STY.KanBanProductId
    ,STY.SprintId
    ,TSK.OriginalEstimateHours
    ,STY.Effort
ORDER BY CASE TSK.[Status]
        WHEN 'Not Started'
            THEN 1
        WHEN 'In Progress'
            THEN 2
        WHEN 'Impeded'
            THEN 3
        WHEN 'Done'
            THEN 4
        END
```

I want to add a row that sums the TaskHoursEstimate column (TSK.OriginalEstimateHours) for the same StoryNumber(STY.[Number]). Below is an example:

[image]

The highlighted section shows what I mean. I would like to add a row where since the storyNumber is the same for these 3 rows (SPK01-22) the row would have 48 in each of them (24+16+8).

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you create an ASCII table? I don't have my glasses on :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. I used a SELECT sub-query:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY TSK.[Status] DESC
        ) AS 'RowNumber'
    ,TSK.PointPerson AS PointPerson
    ,PDT.[Name] AS Project
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN (
                    STY.KanBanProductId IS NOT NULL
                    AND STY.SprintId IS NULL
                    )
                THEN 'KanBan'
            WHEN (
                    STY.KanBanProductId IS NULL
                    AND STY.SprintId IS NOT NULL
                    )
                THEN 'Sprint'
            END
        ) AS ProjectType
    ,STY.[Number] StoryNumber
    ,STY.Title AS StoryTitle
    ,TSK.[Name] AS Task
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), STY.Effort) AS StoryPoints
    ,(
        SELECT SUM(OriginalEstimateHours)
        FROM Task TSK
        LEFT JOIN Story STU ON TSK.StoryId = STU.PK_Story
        LEFT JOIN Sprint SPT ON STU.SprintId = SPT.PK_Sprint
        LEFT JOIN Product PDT ON STU.ProductId = PDT.PK_Product
        LEFT JOIN [User] USR ON TSK.PointPerson = USR.DisplayName
        WHERE TSK.PointPerson LIKE @userParam
            AND (
                (
                    @orgTeamPK = '%'
                    AND (
                        USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] LIKE @orgTeamPK
                        OR USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] IS NULL
                        )
                    )
                OR (
                    @orgTeamPK <> '%'
                    AND (USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] LIKE @orgTeamPK)
                    )
                )
            AND STU.Number LIKE STY.Number
        ) AS StoryHoursEstimate
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), TSK.OriginalEstimateHours) AS TaskHoursEstimate
    ,ISNULL(SUM(DTH.[Hours]), 0) AS WorkHours
    ,MAX(CASE 
            WHEN DTH.Hours != 0
                THEN DTH.ActivityDate
            END) AS LatestActivityDate
    ,TSK.[Status] AS [Status]
FROM Task TSK
LEFT JOIN DailyTaskHours DTH ON TSK.PK_Task = DTH.TaskId
LEFT JOIN Story STY ON TSK.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
LEFT JOIN Sprint SPT ON STY.SprintId = SPT.PK_Sprint
LEFT JOIN Product PDT ON STY.ProductId = PDT.PK_Product
LEFT JOIN [User] USR ON TSK.PointPerson = USR.DisplayName
WHERE TSK.PointPerson LIKE @userParam
    AND TSK.[Status] LIKE @statusParam
    AND PDT.[Name] != 'Overhead Codes'
    AND (
        (
            @orgTeamPK = '%'
            AND (
                USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] LIKE @orgTeamPK
                OR USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] IS NULL
                )
            )
        OR (
            @orgTeamPK <> '%'
            AND (USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] LIKE @orgTeamPK)
            )
        )
    AND TSK.Deleted IS NULL
    AND (
        (
            STY.Number LIKE @search
            OR STY.Number IS NULL
            )
        OR (
            STY.Title LIKE @search
            OR STY.Title IS NULL
            )
        OR (
            TSK.NAME LIKE @search
            OR TSK.NAME IS NULL
            )
        )
GROUP BY LEN(STY.[Number])
    ,STY.[Number]
    ,TSK.[Status]
    ,STY.Title
    ,PDT.[Name]
    ,TSK.PointPerson
    ,TSK.CreateDate
    ,TSK.[Name]
    ,STY.KanBanProductId
    ,STY.SprintId
    ,TSK.OriginalEstimateHours
    ,STY.Effort
ORDER BY CASE TSK.[Status]
        WHEN 'Not Started'
            THEN 1
        WHEN 'In Progress'
            THEN 2
        WHEN 'Impeded'
            THEN 3
        WHEN 'Done'
            THEN 4
        END
```